# Expire time for amplify storage urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

In amplify [guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/js) it says the default for "expires" is no expiry. But when I create a signed url, it expires after sometime. Any idea?

```
await Storage.get(key: string, config: {
  level?: private | protected | public,
  identityId?: string,
  download?: boolean, 
  expires?: number, // validity, in seconds. defaults to no expiry
  contentType?: string 
})
```

Following is my usage.

```
 Storage.get(filepath, {level: 'protected'});
```

Answer (score 2):

It actually defaults to 900 (15 min). Perhaps the documentation was updated since you posted this question. As such, set the expiry value higher and it should resolve the issue.